# Issue in PHP programming. Not executing as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to push data into the database using PHP programming. Below is the part of code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST"){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['num']);
    $bool = true;
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to server
    mysql_select_db("track") or die("Cannot connect to database"); // Connect to database
    $query = mysql_query("Select * from test"); // query the test table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) //dislplay all rows from query
    {
        //$table_test1 = $row['id']; 
        $table_test2 = $row['num']; 

        if($num == table_test2)
        {
            $bool = false;
            Print '<script>alert("Data present already !");</script>';
            Print '<script>window.location.assign("register.php");/script>';
        }
    }
    if($bool)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id,num) VALUES ('$id','$num')");
        Print'<script>alert("Successfully Registered!");</script>';
        Print'<script>window.location.assign("register.php");</script>';
    }   ...
```

In if condition inside while loop,I am trying to check whether the number entered into the post is matching with the number stored in the database in table test. If it is present then don't insert data into the table. But even if the data is present in data base, the if condition is not executing and still inserting data into the table. Could anyone explain me why it is happening.

Comment: don't use mysl_ is depreciated use mysqli, also use prepared statements with mysli or pdo prepared. you might need to check Booby's tables.

Comment: ops! you've missed $ there! typo error is there.

Comment: That code will give you a notice or warning about `table_test2` not being a constant and that php assumes you meant a string. _Never_ ignore or hide such valuable information. In this case it would have clearly told you the issue...

Comment: @arkascha: I am writing the script in notepad++ and simply running it on browser. I didn't get any such warning.

Comment: That most likely means that you 1. do not monitor the http servers error log file (you _cannot_ program php without doing so) or 2. that you suppress such notices (there is a configuration setting for that). You want to change that.

Comment: Oh, and... just for the sake of precision: you do _not_ run that php code inside your browser, I would bet ;-)

Comment: Can you tell me how to monitor server error log files and how to set configuration. I am doing php first time using xampp tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo. You missed the `$` symbol that means is a variable:

```
if($num == table_test2)
```

Change with:

```
if($num == $table_test2)
```

Comment: Yes, its a typo mistake I did. Thanks for the help. Since I am editing code in Notepad++, I won't get any warning from it. Do you have any tool in your mind  which can give warning or error or suggest a possible mistake. It's difficult to know such mistakes when I am simply running the script in browser.

Comment: You enable error-reporting, which would give you "*Undefined constant...*" warnings when the script is run ;-) @VaibhavGautam

Comment: I always develop on Netbeans (PHP+HTML5 version) or SublimeText

Comment: I am using xampp tool. Is there any setting for it there.

Comment: Don't mix concepts. If you want display errors from server you need to configure php.ini. If you need to display the coding errors on the editor you need a good editor.